# In semi-laymen's terms, how to I correctly project 4D lines to a 2D screen, while utilizing perspective transformation

Tags: parametric, projection

I've been trying to write a program that correctly projects 4D lines (4-space) and points upon a 2D screen, so I've first utilized parametric equations to try to clip any lines that might pass through (where p is the distance from (some axis) 0 to the clipping plane) z=p and w=p, then apply perspective transformations to the points and line points to be rendered if they are z>=p and w>=p. Am I going about this right, and if not then how should I go about doing this?

Please use fairly laymen's terms, I am familiar with parametric equations, rotation and transformation matrices, etc., but I'm not so great on the terminology or all of the specific mechanics and properties of matrix multiplication.

I have my attempt at an application of this running at https://editor.p5js.org/hpestock/sketches/Yfagz4Bz3, if it helps.

Comment: By 4D line, you mean time evolving 3D line?

Comment: No, I mean 4-space

Comment: Why do you need the fourth parameter?

Comment: Because I'm trying to project 4-space points and lines onto a 2d plane with perspective transformation, essentially creating a camera's perspective of 4-space if it's projection was reduced to 3d instead of 2d.

Comment: This is like asking "How can you project 3D space onto a 1D line while utilizing perspective transformation?"  That's not possible.  You can only get a single slice of 3D space (a plane) if you do so.  You could try projecting everything down to two dimensions first, but then it wouldn't be a homography.

Comment: I know, that's why I use the projection x = (x/w)/(z/w), y = (y/w)/(z/w)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt. Let $a,b,b_1,b_2,p\in\mathbb{R}^4$ and $s,u,v\in\mathbb{R}$ be such that:
$$L(s) := as+b$$
and
$$P(u,v) := p+b_1u+b_2v$$
describe a line and a 2D plane respectively ($b_1$ and $b_2$ L.I. of course). Since we want to project the line onto the plane, assume for simplicity that $p:=0$.
Then what we want to do is find the vector projections onto the directions , $b_i$, that describe the plane:
$$a_1(s) := proj_{b_1}(as+b) = \langle as+b,b_1\rangle \frac{b_1}{|b_1|^2}\text{ }\text{ and }\text{ }a_2(s):= proj_{b_2}(as+b) = \langle as+b,b_2 \rangle\frac{b_2}{|b_2|^2}$$
and add them for the total projection:
$$\tilde{L}(s):= proj_{P(u,v)}\big(L(s)\big) = (a_1+a_2)(s).$$

---

I tried an example for clarity in $\mathbb{R}^3$ using $b:= (0,0,1)$, $a := (1,1,1)$, $b_1 := (1,0,0)$ and $b_2 := (0,1,0)$. The result I got was $\tilde{L(s)} = (1,1,0)s$. Which when graphed at least looks feasible.

---

*As for perspective, that is another battle entirely IMO. I've tried graphing with Java in a JFrame and altering objects with buttons as to move them around etc. I wanted to say make them disappear when they are far enough away, and make them look like they were getting smaller as they moved towards a horizon point. Wasn't sure exactly how to do this, but I assumed linear scaling w.r.t. distance from the screen into the computer. Note that for lines which are infinite, scaling my not be apparent graphically. So I would pick an interval for $'s'$ at first...*

Comment: I'm having extreme trouble following this, could you clarify what the variables represent and what these equations are notating? I understand that L(s) is notating some line through 4-space, but very little else.

Comment: So yes, $L(s)$ is a line in $\mathbb{R}^4$ starting at $b$ and heading in the direction of $a$, with traversal parameter, $s$. You can think of this as how far in the direction of $a$ you go. Similarly, $P(u,v)$ is a plane in $\mathbb{R}^4$. Except it being 2-dimensional, has two different traversal parameters, $u$ and $v$, corresponding to directions $b_1$ and $b_2$ respectively. The angle brackets seen later represent inner product (or dot product) between the vectors. Lastly, $|v|$ represents magnitude--we divide out here as we are looking for projections onto unit vectors.

Comment: I'm trying to make any lines a. not travel through z=0 or w=0 because to add perspective to them you have to divide by each, and I don't want it to render lines behind the camera, will these clip the lines so they don't pass through z=0 or w=0? I'm really horrible at reading anything about vector math, I'm not well-versed in it

Comment: I would use conditional statements in your perspective function to get rid of things behind the camera. Manipulating computer graphics is a lot of linear algebra, so the vector stuff is worth learning!

Comment: I have a light grasp on some of linear algebra, but I'm really just unsure if what I'm currently doing is properly projecting the fourth dimension, it comes out looking strangely clipped and I'm not certain if that's a property of 4d, or if I've messed something up.

Comment: If I am to clip the z=p,w=p planes of all lines and exclude anything not in the z+ w+ area of 4-space, were I to plot the z and w as x and y on a 2d graph respectively, should that produce a graph that looks like one quarter of a cube, and would that appear properly in a 4-space projection?

Comment: It seems like you are trying to visualize hypercubes by plotting the edges individually and projecting them? I couldn't tell you if the relationships between the lines would be kept in this case. If they are they may not be easy to see.